# Package Manifest 2 - <depend> attribute version does not work

Tags: ros, package, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently looking into versioning my catkin packages and making sure that I am using the correct versions. I am using Package Manifest Version 2 and according to [REP-140](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0140.html#build-depend-multiple), I should be able to specify the versions of my dependencies.

E.g. I have a *package A* (version 1.1) and a *package B* that depends on *package A*. I now would like to make sure, that version 1.1 of *package A* is used when building *package B*. My package.xml's will contain the following (for the sake of simplicity, I only include the relevant parts):

*package A* package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <package format='2'>
  <name>A</name>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  ...
</package>
```

*package B* package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <package format='2'>
  <name>B</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <depend version_eq="1.1.0">A</depend>
  ...
</package>
```

So far so good, everything compiles fine. **However, if I change that depend tag in *package B* package.xml** above, e.g. to

```
<depend version_eq="2.0.0">A</depend>
```

**..it still compiles fine!** *Meaning that it just does not care about the version attribute.*

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

*Edit: I just noticed that a warning is printed:*

```
catkin_package() version mismatch: the package.xml of 'B' build_depends on 'A = 1.0.0', but 'A 0.9.0' found
```

**Is this the expected behaviour or should the build fail?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280048/package-manifest-2---%3Cdepend%3E-attribute-version-does-not-work/) by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2018-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-17**:
Btw: the `depend` tag works just fine, it just doesn't do what you are expecting it to do. But that is something else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I just noticed that a warning is printed:

> ```
> catkin_package() version mismatch: the package.xml of 'B' build_depends on 'A = 1.0.0', but 'A 0.9.0' found
> ```

> Is this the expected behaviour or should the build fail?

Yes (that is the expected behaviour right now), see #q254811 (and [ros-infrastructure/rosdep#325](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/325)).

As far as I know what I write there is still the current situation.

Enforcing versions of dependencies at this point is only possible in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on 2018-01-17**:
I found out that in the catkin_package.cmake script only a WARNING is printed upon a version mismatch, so this behaviour is expected. I think specifying the dependency versions in the package.xml rather than the CMakeLists.txt find_package() is more elegant, but the build should fail upon a mismatch

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-17**:
The build will fail, if you do a `find_package(<DEPENDENCY> X.Y.Z EXACT ..)` in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

I agree that it's less than elegant that you'd have to duplicate that, but the manifest is used for different things (see #q217475).

**Comment by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on 2018-01-17**:
First of all, thanks a lot for the quick&clarifying answers! But if the manifest is used for different things, why is the version attribute in there at all? I see that you are a contributor to ROS, would it make sense to request this feature (build failure) in the ros/catkin repository?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-17**:
I'm a ROS *Industrial* contributor, that is slightly different.

If you want to address this shortcoming in `rosdep`, then I guess [ros-infrastructure/rosdep#325](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/325) would be the starting point.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-17**:
re: why are version attributes there at all: I believe that is covered by #q217475?